# Segmentation error when splitting up a number into digits C

Tags: c, loops, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to write a function in C that will take all the digits of a positive integer and add them together. Here's my code:

```
int num_test(score){
  int total = 0;
  while(score){
   total += (score %10);
    score /= 10;
}
  return total;
}
```

However, I keep receiving `signal: segmentation fault (core dumped)` every time I try to pass anything to it in my main function. I'm relatively new to C, so I'm unsure on how to fix this error.

Comment: I think this is not the problem. In `main`, are you passing in  non-`int` arguments? You are declaring a function with no prototype; turning up the warnings should complain.

Answer (score 0):

Your function 'signature' needs to know the datatype it receives

```
int num_test(score){
  int total = 0;
  while(score){
   total += (score %10);
    score /= 10;
}
  return total;
}
```

```
int num_test( int score ) {
    int total = 0;
    while(score) {
        total += (score %10);
        score /= 10;
    }
    return total;
}
```

Or, there could be other problems in unpublished code.

Answer (score 0):

it's the problem with not specifying a data type for the parameter called `score`

so instead of :

```
int num_test(score)
```

write :

```
int num_test(int score)
```

or what ever you like, it may be `unsigned int score` or whatever you like, but you have to specify a data-type for the function paramter